# Is it OK to compare standard deviation values in relation to one another?

Tags: standard-deviation, z-score

I have a collection of data entries for vitamin D levels in around 1000 people.  It looks roughly like this:

```
id  vitamin_d_score  group
1   35.2             A
2   29.9             A
3   35.6             B
4   39.6             B
5   30.0             A
6   40.5             C
```

etc.

I have z-scored the vitamin D levels so they can be compared in terms of standard deviations (mean = 0, SD = 1).  The results look similar to:

```
id  z_scored_vitamin_d  group
1   0.05                A
2   0.01                A
3   0.05                B
4   0.08                B
5   0.02                A
6   0.09                C
```

etc (note: numbers here are for illustrative purposes only)

I am comparing the means of two sub-groups within this data set.  Subgroup A has a mean z-scored vitamin D score of 0.2.  Subgroup B has a mean z-scored vitamin D score of 0.8.

Am I OK to say that subgroup B has a score that is 0.6 standard deviations higher than subgroup A?  Or when I compare standard deviations do I have to always relate it to the mean, i.e. "subgroup B is 0.8 standard deviations above the mean while subgroup A is only 0.2 standard deviations above the mean".?

Comment: I do not understand why you have multiple z-scores per subgroup. The z-score of a subgroup should consist of the mean of its observations (possibly subtracted by the population mean under $H_0$) divided by the standard deviation in that subgroup. Can you elaborate on your z-score calculation?

Comment: I calculated the z score values for the entire group (A, B and C combined), and I'm looking at how the mean standard deviations (z-score) for group A compares to group B.

Comment: I do not see why you have the intermediate step of z-scoring. Why not just compare the standard deviations of the levels?

Comment: So the standard deviation you referred to is of all data combined? Your statement is then mathematically correct but statistically useless.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "statistically useless"?  I am not sure I understand what you mean.  Thank you

Comment: Your statement in function of standard deviation of the whole group is correct, so the answer to your question is yes. However, you are completely outside regular statistical theory, and cannot perform a z-test for significance this way.